# How to Handle RPC Failure error before reach to OnFailure() at client side ? in GWT

Tags: exception, gwt, rpc

In GWT when RPC fail due to any reason at that time onfailure() method execute at client side.

When onFailure() called at that time actual error is visible in browser's Networks response.

So, My Question is simple how can hide / Modify this actual error with some user friendly Error?

Answer (score 0):

You can override onFailure() method to display what you need, but you cannot modify what a browser shows in the Network tab.

This is an example from my code (LoginException and VersionException are exceptions that my RPC calls throw when necessary):

```
@Override
public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
    if (caught instanceof LoginException) {
        // Redirect a user to login page
        Window.Location.assign("/");
    } else if (caught instanceof IncompatibleRemoteServiceException ||
            caught instanceof VersionException) {
        /*
         * Here I tell a user that a new version is available,
         * so a user needs to refresh the page
         */
    } else {
        // Here I show a simple message about a connection error
    }
}
```

Comment: Ya we can do any thing in OnFailure() method but it shows actual error on browser's network. My goal is to either hide this Error or modify this error with some user friendly error like "internal server error".

Comment: As I said, it's impossible to modify the server response from the client - fortunately. As a user I want to see the real server response if I use browser's developer tools. Most servers, by the way, do respond with something like "Internal server error" if the correct status code is set. I am not sure where is the problem.